# 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment while need to slice and then do assignmnet in tensor array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to find part of a tensor and then assign a constant number to that but I received  this error.
It seems that the assignment to a tensor is not allowed in tensorflow. with that in mind, anyone has any idea how can I accomplish this one?

So for example if the tensor is like this:

```
tf_a2 = tf.Variable(([[2, 5, 1, 4, 3],
                      [1, 6, 4, 2, 3],
                      [0, 0, 0, 6, 6],
                      [2, 1, 1, 3, 3],
                      [4, 4, 1, 2, 3]]))
```

I want to find the elements per row in which they have the same value then I replace any element with N except the first element from left.

For example in the example above, in row=3, three elements =0, so 
I kept the most left one the same as it is and then replace the right elements with the same value with `N`. in the same row there are two element with 6 value,I kept the most left element and replce all elements after that with the same value with `N`.

In row=4 ,1 is repeated two times, I again keep the most left one and replace any the right item which has the same value.

In row =5, 4 is repeated two times again. I keep the most left item, and then replace any item after that with the same value with `N`.

So for N= 9, the result would be:

```
    [[2 5 1 4 3]
     [1 6 4 2 3]
     [0 9 9 6 9]
     [2 1 9 3 9]
     [4 9 1 2 3]]
```

I have the correct code in numpy below:

```
  numpy code:  (a2[:,1:])[a2[:,1:]==a2[:,:-1]] = N
```

but I need to do it in tensorflow , I tried the below code  though it still raises the same error:

```
tf.where(tf.equal(a2[:,1:], a2[:, :-1]),N,a2[:,1:])

The error:
    a2[:,1:][a2[:,1:]==a2[:,:-1]] = N
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

I also looked at the links with the same error here, but they propose a solution exactly regarding their coding which did not match my code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that leads to the mentioned error. Please also include the full traceback.

Comment: Sure, I am adding it

Comment: @a_guest Thank you following with my question, I have updated it, please let me know if I need to add more data.

Comment: You code examples are still not self-contained. Please update with something that we can copy & paste in order to verify the behavior you describe. Furthermore the statement *"I want to find rows which the left and right item are the same, then change it to a constant number like N."* is not clear to me. Could you please elaborate a bit more? What means "left" and "right" element here?

Comment: @a_guest I have updated my question with a good example and explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, " 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment". But there are at least one workaround. One method is to element-wise multiply each element you want to change by zero (in the original matrix) and then create a new matrix (same shape) with all element zeros without the one you want to change. And then you can just add them together to get the desired matrix.

If i understand you're numpy solution correctly for this specific case, you always want to ignore the first column? If that is so, I think this tensorflow solution should work for you (tested and verified for tensorflow version 1.13.1).

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

tf_a2 = tf.Variable(([[2, 5, 1, 4, 3],
                      [1, 6, 4, 2, 3],
                      [0, 0, 0, 6, 6],
                      [2, 1, 1, 3, 3],
                      [4, 4, 1, 2, 3]]))

N=9

first_col_change = tf.zeros([tf_a2.shape[0],1], dtype=tf.int32)
last_cols_change = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf_a2[:,1:], tf_a2[:, :-1]),tf.int32)
change_bool = tf.concat([first_col_change, last_cols_change],axis=-1)
not_change_bool = 1-change_bool
tf_a2_changed = tf_a2*not_change_bool + change_bool*N

print(tf_a2_changed)
```

which gives the output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[2 5 1 4 3]
 [1 6 4 2 3]
 [0 9 9 6 9]
 [2 1 9 3 9]
 [4 9 1 2 3]], shape=(5, 5), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for following my question, I can not run your code successfully it raises this error: FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
  [[Node: Variable/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Variable)]]

Comment: I have also updated the question with better example

Comment: What tensorflow version are you on? try "print("TensorFlow Ver: ", tf.__version__)".  You can try "tf.enable_eager_execution()" it gives you ability to go line by line and print each tensor. great for error search. Just tested the code again here, and works for tensorflow 1.13.1

Comment: I have 1.10.0 tensorflow. Can you also, share your code in which you get its output? I just want to double check

Comment: Okay, I can not get it run inside the session but I could see the output using tf.enable_eager_execution(). Actually, it just gives the correct answer for that specific array, when I changed it to the one I have updated in the question, it did not output the correct answer. can you please read my question again, as I updated throughly how do I want to change the tensor and provided a better array.

Comment: @sariii code is now updated and working for you updated question. The error you got could have been some default int32/float32 mix-up between tensorflow 1.10.0 and 1.13.1, possible fixed now. Try it again

Comment: Yea thank you so much, it is working fine  now, I had to change variable to tf.contrib.eager.Variable to get it run. I also have to see why I can not get the tf10 work with this code. Thanks again.

Comment: @sariii good that it worked! Tensorflow 1.13.1 is an "in-between" release for tensorflow 2.0. Therefore it works without sessions etc, which i don't think 1.10.0 support. I suggest you try out the new version as it will be more similar to the new 2.0 when it get out, and easier to prototype with.

Comment: Thank you again, I was wondering do you have any idea how can iaccomplish this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568981/apply-where-condition-on-3d-tensor-in-tensorflow . I have the working example in NumPy but I need to do it in Tensorflow