# specific kind of slicing over tensor object in tensorflow

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, slice

Summary of the question, Is this kind of slicing and then assignment supported in tensorflow?

```
out[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]] = tf_a1[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]]
final = out[:-1]
```

Lets give the example, I have a tensor like this:

```
tf_a1 = tf.Variable([    [9.968594,  8.655439,  0.,        0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.3356,    0.,        8.8974   ],
                         [0.,        0.,        6.103182,  7.330564 ],
                         [6.609862,  0.,        3.0614321, 0.       ],
                         [9.497023,  0.,        3.8914037, 0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.457685,  8.602337,  0.       ],
                         [0.,        0.,        5.826657,  8.283971 ],
                         [0.,        0.,        0.,        0.       ]])
```

and I have this one:

```
tf_a2 = tf.constant([[1, 2, 5],
                    [1, 4, 6],
                    [0, 7, 7],
                    [2, 3, 6],
                    [2, 4, 7]])
```

Now I want to keep the elements in `tf_a1` in which the combination of n (here n is 2) of them (index of them) is in the value of `tf_a2`. What does it mean?

For example, in `tf_a1`, in the first column, indexes which has value are: (0,3,4). Is there any row in `tf_a2` which contains any combination of these two indexes: (0,3), (0,4) or (3,4). Actually, there is no such row. So all the elements in that column became zero.

Indexes for the second column in `tf_a1` is (0,1) (0,5) (1,5). As you see the record (1,5) is available in the `tf_a2` in the first row. That's why we keep those in the `tf_a1`.

This is the correct numpy code:

```
y,x = np.where(np.count_nonzero(a1p[a2], axis=1) >= n)
out = np.zeros_like(tf_a1)
out[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]] = tf_a1[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]]
final = out[:-1]
```

**This is the expected output of this numpy code (but I need this in tensorflow):**

```
[[0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
 [0.        8.3356    0.        8.8974   ]
 [0.        0.        6.103182  7.330564 ]
 [0.        0.        3.0614321 0.       ]
 [0.        0.        3.8914037 0.       ]
 [0.        8.457685  8.602337  0.       ]
 [0.        0.        5.826657  8.283971 ]]
```

The tensorflow code should be something like this:

```
y, x = tf.where(tf.count_nonzero(tf.gather(tf_a1, tf_a2, axis=0), axis=1) >= n)
out = tf.zeros_like(tf_a1)
out[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]] = tf_a1[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]]
final = out[:-1]
```

This part of the code `tf.gather(tf_a1, tf_a2, axis=0), axis=1)` is doing the numpy like slicing `tf_a1[tf_a2]`

**Update 1**

The only line which does not work its:

```
out[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]] = tf_a1[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]]
final = out[:-1]
```

Any idea how can I accomplish this in tensorflow, is this kind of slicing is supported in tensor object at all?

Any help is appreciated:)

Comment: Your code seems to work, except that you want two separate indices for row and column coordinates, right? You can just slice like this: `idx = tf.where(...); r, c = idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]`

Comment: Hmm, it worked for me. What is the shape of `idx`? I get `idx.shape >>> TensorShape([8, 2])` for this example.

Comment: Actually,it raises an error in the last line when I want to do the slicing, in this line `out[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]] = tf_a1[tf_a2[y],x[:,None]]` error: `TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor: id=65, shape=(8,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2])>`

Comment: I think I need to do learn fundamentally about the slicing in tensorflow. for now, I appreciate if I can have the working version of this, so I can have something to work on how the slicing is working in tensorflow.

Comment: Still a green bean myself, so having a little difficulty getting this to work. Will update if I can figure this out. Hopefully someone else with a little more experience will get this in the meantime :p

Comment: In the meantime, could you add the expected output of the numpy operation here? That'd be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @cs95 sure I will update, thank you so much for putting time:)

Comment: I have updted the question with the expected output