# non continuous index slicing on tensor object in tensorflow (Advanced indexing like numpy)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, slice

I have looked at different ways of slicing in tensorflow, namely, `tf.gather` and `tf.gather_nd`.
In tf.gather, it just slices over a dimension, and also in `tf.gather_nd` it just accepts one `indices` to be applied over the input tensor.

What I need is different, I want to slice over the input tensor using two different tensor;one slices over the rows the second slices over the column and they are not in the same shape necessarily.

For example:

suppose this is my input tensor in which I want to extract part of it.

```
input_tf = tf.Variable([ [9.968594,  8.655439,  0.,        0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.3356,    0.,        8.8974   ],
                         [0.,        0.,        6.103182,  7.330564 ],
                         [6.609862,  0.,        3.0614321, 0.       ],
                         [9.497023,  0.,        3.8914037, 0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.457685,  8.602337,  0.       ],
                         [0.,        0.,        5.826657,  8.283971 ],
                         [0.,        0.,        0.,        0.       ]])
```

the second is:

```
 rows_tf = tf.constant (
[[1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 4, 7]])
```

The third tensor:

```
columns_tf = tf.constant(
[[1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2]])
```

Now, I want to slice over `input_tf` using `rows_tf` and `columns_tf`. index `[1 2 5]` in rows and `[1]` in `columns_tf`. Again, rows `[1 2 5]` with `[2]` in `columns_tf`.

Or, `[1 4 6]` with `[2]`.

Overall, each index in the `rows_tf`, with the same index in `columns_tf`will extract part of the `input_tf`.

**so, the expected output will be:**

```
[[8.3356,    0.,        8.457685 ],
 [0.,        6.103182,  8.602337 ],
 [8.8974,    7.330564,  0.       ],
 [0.,        3.8914037, 5.826657 ],
 [8.8974,    0.,        8.283971 ],
 [6.103182,  3.0614321, 5.826657 ],
 [7.330564,  0.,        8.283971 ],
 [6.103182,  3.8914037, 0.       ]]
```

for example, here the first row `[8.3356,    0.,        8.457685 ]` is being extracted using

```
rows in rows_tf [1,2,5] and column in columns_tf [1](row 1 and column 1, row 2 and column 1 and row 5 and column 1 in the input_tf)
```

There were a couple of questions regarding slicing in tensorflow, though they used `tf.gather` or `tf.gather_nd` and `tf.stack` which it did not give my desired output.

No need to mention that in `numpy` we can easily do that by calling: `input_tf[rows_tf, columns_tf]`.

I also, looked at this advanced indexing which tries to simulate the advanced indexing available in numpy, however it still is not like numpy flexible https://github.com/SpinachR/ubuntuTest/blob/master/beautifulCodes/tensorflow_advanced_index_slicing.ipynb

This is what I have tried which is not correct:

```
tf.gather(tf.transpose(tf.gather(input_tf,rows_tf)),columns_tf)
```

the dimension output of this code is `(8, 1, 3, 8)` which is incorrect totally.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should edit your question so all constants are formatted properly (add `,`)

Comment: @DSC you are right, I will do now, thanks

Comment: Why were you not pleased with the output of the 'gather' operations you mention? Sounds like it could work. Is it because it returns it flatten? if so you could reshape it knowing the dimensions of 'rows_tf' and 'columns_tf'

Comment: @Ben thanks for following, actually there is something wrong as the dimension of the output becomes `(8, 1, 3, 8)` which is incorrect(it also added one more dimension!!)

Comment: Once you have `scatter_idx` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640222/using-while-loop-over-the-tensor-for-creating-a-mask-in-tensorflow?noredirect=1#comment99884193_56640222 you should be able to use `tf.gather_nd(params=input_tf, indices=scatter_idx)` followed by a `tf.reshape` to get your desired shape.

Comment: @greeness I do not get the expected output which I have put in the question though, the shape is correct, but the ultimate matrix is not. for example 8.3356 has to be my output in index (0,0) but when applying tf.gather_nd ... I got 0. in index(0,0)

Comment: I copied the full code below as an answer, you can use the similar way from any other answers in your other thread to get `sparse_indices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to first get the sparse indices (by concatenating row index and column index) as a list. Then you can use `gather_nd` to retrieve the values.

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()
input_tf = tf.Variable([ [9.968594,  8.655439,  0.,        0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.3356,    0.,        8.8974   ],
                         [0.,        0.,        6.103182,  7.330564 ],
                         [6.609862,  0.,        3.0614321, 0.       ],
                         [9.497023,  0.,        3.8914037, 0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.457685,  8.602337,  0.       ],
                         [0.,        0.,        5.826657,  8.283971 ],
                         [0.,        0.,        0.,        0.       ]])
rows_tf = tf.constant (
[[1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 4, 7]])
columns_tf = tf.constant(
[[1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2]])
rows_tf = tf.reshape(rows_tf, shape=[-1, 1])
columns_tf = tf.reshape(
    tf.tile(columns_tf, multiples=[1, 3]), 
    shape=[-1, 1])
sparse_indices = tf.reshape(
    tf.concat([rows_tf, columns_tf], axis=-1), 
    shape=[-1, 2])

v = tf.gather_nd(input_tf, sparse_indices)
v = tf.reshape(v, [-1, 3])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  #print 'rows\n', sess.run(rows_tf)
  #print 'columns\n', sess.run(columns_tf)
  print sess.run(v)
```

Result would be:

```
[[ 8.3355999   0.          8.45768547]
 [ 0.          6.10318184  8.60233688]
 [ 8.8973999   7.33056402  0.        ]
 [ 0.          3.89140368  5.82665682]
 [ 8.8973999   0.          8.28397083]
 [ 6.10318184  3.06143212  5.82665682]
 [ 7.33056402  0.          8.28397083]
 [ 6.10318184  3.89140368  0.        ]]
```

Comment: I genuinely and really appreciate your help:)

Comment: np, have fun with tf. :)

Comment: I've got one confusion here, which sounds like a logical problem. exactly this code runs fine, when I include this code in my program it output incorrectly. I found the source of the problem, but it does not make sense to me. I was wondering if you have any idea regarding this. `rows_tf` and `columns_tf` given at `tf.constant' here, but in my code they are the result of some other process. if I give it `tf.constant` like here it works exactly fine but once I changed it anything rather than `tf.constant` the output will be incorrec the same as I report above. why it should be like this?

Comment: Did you get `rows_tf`, `columns_tf` correctly? you might want to include all of your code to clarify.  feel free to update your question here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568981/specific-kind-of-slicing-over-tensor-object-in-tensorflow or maybe start a new thread. i am happy to take a look shortly.

Comment: Yea `rows_tf` and `columns_tf` in my code are exactly the same as the one I presented here. I really appreciate if you can have a look. regarding the link you put here, that is one I am trying to do, which I could not accomplish at once and sounds it was hard for anybody else to do it, thats why I broke it down, to do it step by step(I might not have an efficient code). I update with my code here, however my ultimate goal is the link you shared.

Comment: again many thanks, I just coppied the code here, three line of code in numpy ended up with this in tf :)

Comment: Please let me know if its not clear or you think I need to start a new question.

Comment: right, I am totally confused by your code. can you revert it and create a new thread? please give a reference to your `alp` method. I did not find any reference to it in a simple search ("alp numpy") on google.

Comment: glad to know that.

Comment: if you have time can you please have a look  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673546/how-to-do-slice-assignment-while-the-slice-itself-is-a-tensor-in-tensorflow if this last question finished I have done the thing Im trying to achieve, later I just need to make it effiecient. Thank you again:)