# how to do slice assignment while the slice itself is a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice, variable-assignment

I want to do slice assignment in tensorflow. I got to know that I can use:

```
my_var = my_var[4:8].assign(tf.zeros(4))
```

base on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157723/how-to-do-slice-assignment-in-tensorflow).

as you see in `my_var[4:8]` we have specific indices 4, 8 here for slicing and then assignment.

My case is different I want to do slicing based on a tensor and then do the assignment.

```
out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[8,4], dtype=tf.float32))

 rows_tf = tf.constant (
[[1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 4, 7]])

columns_tf = tf.constant(
[[1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2]])

changed_tensor = [[8.3356,    0.,        8.457685 ],
                  [0.,        6.103182,  8.602337 ],
                  [8.8974,    7.330564,  0.       ],
                  [0.,        3.8914037, 5.826657 ],
                  [8.8974,    0.,        8.283971 ],
                  [6.103182,  3.0614321, 5.826657 ],
                  [7.330564,  0.,        8.283971 ],
                  [6.103182,  3.8914037, 0.       ]]
```

Also, this is the `sparse_indices` tensor, which is the concat of `rows_tf` and `columns_tf` making the whole indices that need to be updated(in case it can help:)

```
sparse_indices = tf.constant(
[[1 1]
 [2 1]
 [5 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 2]
 [5 2]
 [1 3]
 [2 3]
 [5 3]
 [1 2]
 [4 2]
 [6 2]
 [1 3]
 [4 3]
 [6 3]
 [2 2]
 [3 2]
 [6 2]
 [2 3]
 [3 3]
 [6 3]
 [2 2]
 [4 2]
 [4 2]])
```

What  I want to do is to do this simple assignment:

```
out[rows_tf, columns_tf] = changed_tensor
```

for that I am doing this:

```
out[rows_tf:column_tf].assign(changed_tensor)
```

However, I received this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1,8,3], [1,8,1], and [1] instead. [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/
```

this is the expected output:

```
[[0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
 [0.        8.3356    0.        8.8974   ]
 [0.        0.        6.103182  7.330564 ]
 [0.        0.        3.0614321 0.       ]
 [0.        0.        3.8914037 0.       ]
 [0.        8.457685  8.602337  0.       ]
 [0.        0.        5.826657  8.283971 ]
 [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]]
```

Any idea how can I finish this mission?

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: `tf.scatter_nd_update` should work for your case. In this function, `indices` should be the `scatter_idx` which is a list of 2-d indices `[[1,1], [2,1], [5,1], ...]`. The `updates` is the expected values on these indices. The tf documentation on `tf.scatter_nd` has good examples on usage.

Comment: @greeness sparse_index = [[1 1]
 [2 1]
 [5 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 2]
 [5 2]
 [1 3]
 [2 3]
 [5 3]
 [1 2]
 [4 2]
 [6 2]
 [1 3]
 [4 3]
 [6 3]
 [2 2]
 [3 2]
 [6 2]
 [2 3]
 [3 3]
 [6 3]
 [2 2]
 [4 2]
 [4 2]] which does not match with `updates` (8,3) thats why it raises error `Outer dimensions of indices and update must match. Indices shape: [24,2], updates shape:[8,3] [Op:ScatterNd]` . Thanks:)

Comment: You should `tf.reshape` your `updates` tensor to shaped as `[-1]` otherwise it won't match the shape of `indices`. I suggest you read carefully the documentation on "tensorflow sparse tensor". That would help you in the long term. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor

Comment: @greeness you are right I need to spend a good amount of time on that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: still not able to get it run even after reshaping:|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example (extended from tf documentation `tf.scatter_nd_update` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update)) should help.

You want to first combine your row_indices and column_indices into a list of 2d indices, which is `indices` argument to `tf.scatter_nd_update`. Then you fed a list of expected values, which is `updates`.

```py
ref = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[8,4], dtype=tf.float32))
indices = tf.constant([[0, 2], [2, 2]])
updates = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0])

update = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, indices, updates)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  print sess.run(update)
```

```
Result:

[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Specifically for your data,

```py
ref = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[8,4], dtype=tf.float32))
changed_tensor = [[8.3356,    0.,        8.457685 ],
                  [0.,        6.103182,  8.602337 ],
                  [8.8974,    7.330564,  0.       ],
                  [0.,        3.8914037, 5.826657 ],
                  [8.8974,    0.,        8.283971 ],
                  [6.103182,  3.0614321, 5.826657 ],
                  [7.330564,  0.,        8.283971 ],
                  [6.103182,  3.8914037, 0.       ]]
updates = tf.reshape(changed_tensor, shape=[-1])
sparse_indices = tf.constant(
[[1, 1],
 [2, 1],
 [5, 1],
 [1, 2],
 [2, 2],
 [5, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [2, 3],
 [5, 3],
 [1, 2],
 [4, 2],
 [6, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [4, 3],
 [6, 3],
 [2, 2],
 [3, 2],
 [6, 2],
 [2, 3],
 [3, 3],
 [6, 3],
 [2, 2],
 [4, 2],
 [4, 2]])

update = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, sparse_indices, updates)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  print sess.run(update)

Result:

[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          8.3355999   0.          8.8973999 ]
 [ 0.          0.          6.10318184  7.33056402]
 [ 0.          0.          3.06143212  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          8.45768547  8.60233688  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          5.82665682  8.28397083]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

Comment: Sorry for the many comments. I got your example, but say my `indices` shape is `(24,2)` and `updates` shape is `(8,3)` when I reshape the updates to `shape=[-1, 2]` Im still receiving an error ` Outer dimensions of indices and update must match. Indices shape: [24,2], updates shape:[12,2] [Op:ScatterNd]`. I appreciate if you can let me know what thing is wrong here

Comment: You should reshape the updates to [-1], not [-1,2]. The expected shape of `updates` is (k,) and the shape of `indices` is (k, 2). in your case, k = 24.

Comment: you mean like this `tf.reshape(updates,shape=[-1,1]))` ?

Comment: I think I am totally lost, the order of the argument in the documentation is different from yours, I dont know if I am missing something? also, i updated the question with `sparse_indices` in case it will be easier to follow why im getting the error. again many thanks for putting the time:)

Comment: I have no idea why it does not work on your side. I integrate your data. answer revised.

Comment: Actually, I am getting this error, but not with your reproducible example but in my side. I just updated the question. it is a long and weird error!

Comment: Are you running on CPU or GPU, TPU?

Comment: Im running on GPU, GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]

Comment: You tensorflow binary seems to not support the scatter_nd_upate on GPU. You might need to find an appropriate binary. this github issue might help: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7026

Comment: thank you so much for all your help, so I should either change the approach or fix  the tensorflow version. do you think this can be done in any other way that does not need scatter_nd?

Comment: np. You could cast your scatter_idx into a boolean matrix as mask, then you probably don't need to do scatter_update. But I do believe scatter update will run faster thus more optimized for your problem.

Comment: I think my tensorflow is not the problem here, as im able to run your code successfully, but when injecting in my code it raises this weird error. pleas share your idea with me any time if you think any other thing could be the reason. Thank U:)

Comment: Many Many thanks @greeness, you are life saver. I definitely study more and put more time. Finally got it run. Again thank you :)

Comment: GREAT, how did you get it run? Why the error was gone?

Comment: Actually I just unistalled and reinstalled tensorflow, plus I comment tf.enable_eager_execution() and use the session to get it run!

Comment: It sounds with enable_eager_execution it wont run successfully in!!

Comment: I was wondering do you have any idea regarding this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730261/how-to-reshape-text-data-to-be-suitable-for-lstm-model-in-keras thank you in advance :)